# WPF Binding Order - How To Change?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, prism

I have a toggle button which i bind its 'Tag' property to an object. I then bind the 'IsChecked' property to its 'Tag' property.
My problem is that the 'IsChecked' is called first when the window loads and the 'Tag' second.
How could i make the 'Tag' property bind first?

```
<ToggleButton>

    <ToggleButton.Tag>
        <Bind An Object...>
    </ToggleButton.Tag>

    <ToggleButton.IsChecked>
        <Binding Converter="{StaticResource SomeConverter}" Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
    </ToggleButton.IsChecked>

</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why does order matter? Is it because your converter doesn't handle the case when the value is `null`, because it should - even if it returns `Binding.DoNothing`. When Tag is set to something, your IsChecked binding should refresh and your converter should run again. Is that not the case?

Comment: You are right. As per your answer i have rechecked my bindings and found a mistake. Afer fixing, indeed the IsChecked binding converter is called again when the 'Tag' binding changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind this source (source what you binding to `Tag`) directly to `Tag` and `IsChecked`, then you don't have `IsChecked` binding dependend on `Tag` and you dont care about race condition and you don't need any order.

Comment: Thank you. But Kent answer solved my problem. I also think that there are no race conditions here as all the properties are dependency props.